# Making simple game of Battleship

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a simple Battleship game. It is a one player game versus the computer. So far I am only able to input the positions of my ship without my program breaking lol. 
I am trying to generate random coordinates for the computer, but I can not figure out the logic to place them beside each other (vertical or horizontal) without overlapping them. 

I still need conditions for sunken ships and when the game is over, but I don't know how to go about it. My best (and only) process was to loop through the elements of each of the players and computers hit boards (the hits recorded for both computer and player) and count if there is 5 'A', 3 'C', and 2 'D' on the board. If there is, then that player wins.

```
from random import random, randrange

def emptyBoard():
    empBoard = [ ['*','*','*','*','*','*','*'],
             ['*','*','*','*','*','*','*'],
             ['*','*','*','*','*','*','*'],
             ['*','*','*','*','*','*','*'],
             ['*','*','*','*','*','*','*'],
             ['*','*','*','*','*','*','*'],
             ['*','*','*','*','*','*','*']]
    return empBoard

def placeMyShips(myBoard):

    for a in range(5):
        x,y = eval(input('Enter coordinate of Aircarrier: '))
        myBoard [x][y] = 'A' 

    for c in range(3):
        x1,y1 = eval(input('Enter coordinate of Cruiser: '))
        myBoard [x1][y1] = 'C'
    for d in range(2):
        x2,y2 = eval(input('Enter coordinate of Destroyer: '))
        myBoard [x2][y2] = 'D'

    print ('\tMy Fleet')
    for i in myBoard:
        print (i)

    return myBoard

def placeCompShips(compBoard):

    for a in range (5):
        x= randrange(0,5)
        y= x+1      
        compBoard[x][y]= 'A'

    for c in range (3):
        x1= randrange(0,5)
        y1= x1+1
        if compBoard [x1][y1] == '*':
            compBoard[x1][y1]= 'C'            

    for d in range (2):
        x2= randrange(0,5)
        y2= x2+1
        if compBoard [x2][y2] =='*':
        compBoard[x2][y2] = 'D'

    return compBoard

def myMoves(compBoard,myHitBoard):  
    x,y = eval(input('Enter your move as coordinate: '))
    if compBoard[x][y] == 'A':
        myHitBoard[x][y] =='A'
        print('Computer: You hit my Aircarrier')

    elif compBoard [x][y] == 'C':
        myHitBoard[x][y] =='C'
        print('Computer: You hit my Cruiser')

    elif compBoard [x][y] == 'D':
        myHitBoard[x][y] =='D'
        print('Computer: You hit my Destroyer')

    else:
        myHitBoard [x][y] = 'M'
        print('Computer: Shot was a miss')

    print ('My hits on the computer')
    for i in myHitBoard:
        print (i)

    return myHitBoard

def compMoves(myBoard,compHitBoard):

    x,y = eval(input('Enter your move as coordinate '))
    if myBoard[x][y] == 'A':          
        compHitBoard [x][y] = 'A'
        print('Player: You hit my Aircarrier')
    elif myBoard [x][y] == 'C':
        compHitBoard[x][y] =='C'
        print('Player: You hit my Cruiser')
    elif myBoard [x][y] == 'D':
        compHitBoard[x][y] =='D'
        print('Player: You hit my Destroyer')
    else:
        compHitBoard [x][y] = 'M'
        print('Player: Shot was a miss')
    return compHitBoard


def intro():
    print('BATTLESHIP')
    print('This is a one player game versus the computer')

def main():
    intro()

    placeMyShips(emptyBoard())
    placeCompShips(emptyBoard())

main()
```

Comment: You might wanna use a 2d array in numpy or even a pandas object to make indexing easier?  Ie you could give labels to the collumns and rows and refer to data as "Board['A']['2']"  and maybe the value can be True or False, where True means a ship is there and False it isnt.

Comment: What is not working? Be more specific, "is this the best way to approach this" is very vague.

Comment: Eek this sounds like a whole lot of problems tied into one question. I would try narrowing to ONE issue and asking about that one, then work on another on your own before asking a second question, and so on.

Comment: @AdamSmith Haha I know! My main issue is the parameter passing problem. But other help to the any problems would be great!

Comment: @sm15 I began a quick and dirty (but best-effort) implementation [here](https://bitbucket.org/smith_adam/battleship). You're really going to get value from modular development here. I'll build some unit tests later on this week and see if I can't get more of the game proper up and running, however in `ships.Ship.__init__` there's a section that handles ***PLAYER*** overlapping ships. Feel free to clone and work on it with me if you'd like, otherwise I hope the small amount of code I put in can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I really appreciate the effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's unlikely that you're going to get a good answer to this question because of its breadth, however what I THINK you're trying to do with your parameter issue is more like:

```
def main():
    intro()

    my_board = placeMyShips(emptyBoard())
    my_hit_board = emptyBoard()
    comp_board = placeCompShips(emptyBoard())
    comp_hit_board = emptyBoard()

    myMoves(comp_board, my_hit_board)
```

Note also my variable names. Functions shouldn't use mixedCase names except where it's already established in that project (e.g. this new project and every other should use lowercase_names) as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)